# Joining multiple tables with WHERE clause for each table

Tags: postgresql, join, indexing, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

Ex.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.idx = B.idx
JOIN C ON A.idx = C.idx
WHERE A.create_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
  OR A.last_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
  OR B.create_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
  OR B.last_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
  OR C.create_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
  OR C.last_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31';
```

It is a PostgreSQL DB

While multi-joining the tables, I want to `SELECT` only the data where the `create_dt` or `last_dt` of each table is the latest.
However, there is a problem that the speed is too slow. How to solve in this case?

Performance is fine when I leave only the A table `WHERE` condition.

Comment: *I want to SELECT only the data where the create_dt or last_dt of each table is **the latest**.* ?? This is unclear. The latest in what data collection? within the row? the group? the table? total rowset? Show an example..

Answer (score 2):

> I want to `SELECT` only the data where the `create_dt` or `last_dt` of each table is the latest.

Then you certainly cannot join on `idx` since the latest per table won't share the same `idx` value.

Your query does not do what you say. This one does:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM  (
   (
   SELECT GREATEST(create_dt, last_dt) AS latest_a, *
   FROM   a
   WHERE  create_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
   ORDER  BY create_dt DESC
   LIMIT 1
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT GREATEST(create_dt, last_dt) AS latest_a, *
   FROM   a
   WHERE  last_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
   ORDER  BY last_dt DESC
   LIMIT 1
   )
   ORDER BY latest_a
   LIMIT 1
   ) a
CROSS JOIN  (
   (
   SELECT GREATEST(create_dt, last_dt) AS latest_b, *
   FROM   b
   WHERE  create_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
   ORDER  BY create_dt DESC
   LIMIT 1
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT GREATEST(create_dt, last_dt) AS latest_b, *
   FROM   b
   WHERE  last_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
   ORDER  BY last_dt DESC
   LIMIT 1
   )
   ORDER BY latest_b
   LIMIT 1
   ) b
CROSS JOIN  (
   (
   SELECT GREATEST(create_dt, last_dt) AS latest_c, *
   FROM   a
   WHERE  create_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
   ORDER  BY create_dt DESC
   LIMIT 1
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT GREATEST(create_dt, last_dt) AS latest_c, *
   FROM   a
   WHERE  last_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
   ORDER  BY last_dt DESC
   LIMIT 1
   )
   ORDER BY latest_c
   LIMIT 1
   ) c -- USING (idx);
```

All parentheses required.
A bit verbose. But it's as fast as this gets - provided you have these indexes:

```sql
CREATE INDEX a_create_dt_idx ON A (create_dt);
CREATE INDEX a_last_dt_idx ON A (last_dt);

CREATE INDEX b_create_dt_idx ON B (create_dt);
CREATE INDEX b_last_dt_idx ON B (last_dt);

CREATE INDEX c_create_dt_idx ON C (create_dt);
CREATE INDEX c_last_dt_idx ON C (last_dt);
```

It will be two index seeks per table, directly picking the one qualifying row every time.

I am joining with an unconditional `CROSS JOIN`, since each subquery returns exactly *one* row, provided at least one qualifies.

If one of the subqueries finds no row, the result is empty. Maybe you really want a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to preserve results from the other tables if one comes up empty. Or just 3 result rows.

Then again, I wouldn't be surprised if you didn't exactly say what you really need. My educated guess: you want something like this (the latest row **per idx** from each table):

```sql
(
SELECT DISTINCT ON (idx) 'a_latest_create_dt' AS what, *
FROM   a
WHERE  create_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
ORDER  BY idx DESC, create_dt DESC, last_dt DESC
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT DISTINCT ON (idx) 'a_latest_last_dt' AS what, *
FROM   a
WHERE  last_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
ORDER  BY idx DESC, last_dt DESC, create_dt DESC
)

UNION ALL
(
SELECT DISTINCT ON (idx) 'b_latest_create_dt' AS what, *
FROM   b
WHERE  create_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
ORDER  BY idx DESC, create_dt DESC, last_dt DESC
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT DISTINCT ON (idx) 'b_latest_last_dt' AS what, *
FROM   b
WHERE  last_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
ORDER  BY idx DESC, last_dt DESC, create_dt DESC
)

UNION ALL
(
SELECT DISTINCT ON (idx) 'c_latest_create_dt' AS what, *
FROM   c
WHERE  create_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
ORDER  BY idx DESC, create_dt DESC, last_dt DESC
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT DISTINCT ON (idx) 'c_latest_last_dt' AS what, *
FROM   c
WHERE  last_dt BETWEEN '2023-05-01' AND '2023-05-31'
ORDER  BY idx DESC, last_dt DESC, create_dt DESC
)
ORDER BY idx, what;
```

This time I list the latest rows per idx for each table: one for `create_dt`, one for `last_dt`. Makes 6 rows if there is one in the time frame for every flavor.

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Assuming all involved columns are `NOT NULL`. Else you may have to do more ...

Matching indexes:

```sql
CREATE INDEX a_create_dt_idx ON A (idx, create_dt);
CREATE INDEX a_last_dt_idx ON A (idx, last_dt);

CREATE INDEX b_create_dt_idx ON B (idx, create_dt);
CREATE INDEX b_last_dt_idx ON B (idx, last_dt);

CREATE INDEX c_create_dt_idx ON C (idx, create_dt);
CREATE INDEX c_last_dt_idx ON C (idx, last_dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try adding the following indices to the three tables:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_a ON A (idx, create_dt, last_dt);
CREATE INDEX idx_b ON B (idx, create_dt, last_dt);
CREATE INDEX idx_c ON C (idx, create_dt, last_dt);
```

These indices, if used, should speed up the joins in your query.

Comment: Thank you. My cowoker said me that date columns aren't usually used as indexes. 
So the index request was denied.

Comment: @younghyun; Date columns are as good as any for indexes. Question is whether the index fits the query, and whether the filter is selective enough.